# CSS Text to a Picture positioning

Tags: html, css

[I'm trying to build this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz7wH.png)

I have trouble with the positioning of the text. It's awlays under the picture. I saw the code from the site, that I'm trying to build (I'm beginner with the web desing, making copies of other sites, to practise, don't upload them, or use them) and it doens't have "float" (picture or text). [This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUCrL.png).
Can you giv me some advice how to do it?
Thanks for answering, also sorry for my fck'd english.

Comment: You should post your code, not pictures

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve using _words_, not (just) _pictures_. That picture might become unavailable in the future, and that would make your whole question lose any value to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
display: inline-block;
```

around the text that comes after the image

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fj2f887v/

The solution is to combine `float` and `margin`. In this example you should use `float` for image wrapper and for right content, image width plus some margin. For example

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/80x80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item .avatar {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}

.item .text {
  margin-left: 85px;
}
```